# Solving linear systems by preconditioned conjugate gradient algorithm

Tags: systems-of-equations, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra, jacobian

Let a linear system, AU=F, be arisen from the second order central finite difference approximation to a Poisson boundary value problem as follows

$$−\Delta u = f \in \ \Omega := (0,1) \times (0,1)$$

where $u = 0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$ and

$$f = 2 \pi^2 \sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$

The exact solution $u = \sin(\pi x) \sin(\pi y)$. The grid size $h = \frac 1n$ such that the grid points $(x_i, y_j)$ $with\ x_i=i h\ and\ y_j = j h\ for\ i, j=0,1,2,...,n.$ The grid points are then ordered from left to right and bottom to top to produce the linear system with A being symmetric positive definite.

Write a program that compute the linear system by the preconditioned conjugate gradient algorithm using the Jacobi preconditioning.

You then use your program to do all the numerical experiments using an initial guess of zero and the iteration rule: Terminate the iteration as soon as the relative residual norm

$$\| F − AU \|_2 < 10^{−5} \|F\|_2$$

I am unsure where to start on this problem in terms of setting up the matrix A, U and F. The whole intro confuses me. I understand the programming end of it but to set up the matrix does not make sense to me, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what a second order central finite difference approximation is?

Comment: Somewhat, we have gone over it in class briefly. It has to do with approximation of the derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to calculate the numbers $u_{i,j}$, where $0 < i,j < n$, where $u_{i,j}$ is your approximation to the value of the function $u$ evaluated at the corresponding point $(\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n})$.

Note that you do *not* need to calculate the values $u_{0,j}$, $u_{i,n}$, etc because you already know they are zero.

Because these are the numbers that you are trying to calculate, these are your *unknowns*. That is, $U$ is a column vector with $(n-1)^2$ elements. You can use either row-major or column-major order; it doesn't matter. But let's say it's this:

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}u_{1,1} \\ u_{2,1} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n-1,1} \\ u_{1,2} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n-1,n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

It's important to work this out first, because now you can consider the linear system as a whole. You want the number of equations to equal the number of unknowns, otherwise the problem is either underdetermined or overdetermined. So $A$ should be a $(n-1)^2 \times (n-1)^2$ matrix, and $F$ should be a column vector with $(n-1)^2$ elements.

Moreover, think hard about the similarity between $AU = F$ and $-\Delta u = f$. We know that $U$ corresponds to $u$, and so if you squint at this really hard, you may be able to see that $A$ should correspond to $-\Delta$ (somehow) and $F$ should correspond to $f$.

Long story short, if $F$ is a column vector with $(n-1)^2$ elements and it corresponds to $f$, chances are very good that it's going to be $f$ evaluated at the lattice points:

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}f_{1,1} \\ f_{2,1} \\ \vdots \\ f_{n-1,1} \\ f_{1,2} \\ \vdots \\ f_{n-1,n-1}\end{bmatrix}\,\mathrm{where}\,\,f_{i,j} = f\left(\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)$$

So now, this just leaves $A$. We want to find a $(n-1)^2 \times (n-1)^2$ matrix $A$ such that $AU$ is a finite difference approximation to $-\Delta u$ evaluated at the corresponding points.

We know that:

$$\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$$

The central finite difference approximation to the second derivative is:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \approx \frac{f(x - h) - 2 f(x) + f(x + h)}{h^2}$$

So:

$$\Delta u(x,y) \approx \frac{1}{h^2}\left( u(x - h,y) + u(x + h,y) + u(x, y - h) + u(x, y + h) - 4 u(x,y) \right)$$

That is:

$$-\Delta u_{i,j} \approx -\frac{1}{h^2} \left( u_{i-1,j} + u_{i+1,j} + u_{i,j-1} + u_{i,j+1} -4u_{i,j}\right)$$

Using the boundary conditions $u_{0,j} = u_{n,j} = u_{i,0} = u_{i,n} = 0$, this gives you enough information to construct $A$. For example, let's suppose that $n = 4$. Then you get the linear system:

$$-\frac{1}{4^2}\begin{bmatrix}-4 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 1 & -4 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  1 & -4 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 1 &  0 &  0 & -4 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  1 & -4 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 & -4 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 & -4 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 & -4 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 & -4
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u_{1,1} \\ u_{2,1} \\ u_{3,1} \\ u_{1,2} \\ u_{2,2} \\ u_{3,2} \\ u_{1,3} \\ u_{2,3} \\ u_{3,3}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}f_{1,1} \\ f_{2,1} \\ f_{3,1} \\ f_{1,2} \\ f_{2,2} \\ f_{3,2} \\ f_{1,3} \\ f_{2,3} \\ f_{3,3}\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally, we need to talk about the constant factor $-\frac{1}{h^2}$. You see, to use conjugate gradient methods to solve this system, $A$ needs to be symmetric and positive definite. It's clearly symmetric, but is it positive definite? $A$ is a negative constant multiplied by a matrix whose diagonal terms are all negative, so this may not be immediately obvious to you.

I'll let you discover the answer for yourself, but long story short, if it turns out to be negative definite, negating both sides fixes the problem.

Comment: So programming this I would write loops based on n to create each matrix and solve from there correct? @Pseudonym

Comment: How you implement it is up to you. I will note that for large $n$, $A$ is going to require a lot of storage if you don't take advantage of its sparse structure. $A_{p,q}$ must be zero if $p$ and $q$ represent the coordinates of cells that don't touch.

Comment: Ok, so in this program I have to run multiple different n's. Is there a simpler way to create A than create a zero matrix size $(n−1)^2×(n−1)^2 $ then going row by row or column by column to create the needed matrix? @Pseudonym

Comment: @Mathmaticsproof First off, note that $A$ is sparse and has at most 5 non-zero entries in each row and column. This is important, because it means you can store it in $O(n)$ space rather than $O(n^2)$. Second, try building these matrixes for different $n$ and see if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: Ok I guess I am still having trouble understanding how you created the matrix A. I understand everything except why you get 1's in the places you do. u and f make sense, the constant factor makes sense, the diagonal makes sense but how do you determine where you will get a 1 or a 0 for the rest of the matrix? @Pseudonym

Comment: All I can suggest is start with $\Delta u(x,y) \approx \frac{1}{h^2}\left( u(x - h,y) + u(x + h,y) + u(x, y - h) + u(x, y + h) - 4 u(x,y) \right)$ and work out the 4 by 4 case for yourself. There is no substitute for doing it.